# What to do with php after jquery .serialize()

Tags: php, jquery, forms, serialization, form-submit

Ok somehow im having the hardest time figuring this out so i want to do an call ajax with a form and im using jquery to serialize it with .serialize(). The data being sent to php looks something like this

```
key1=value&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

And im using a post request. It looks simple enough, but somehow im having a really hard time figuring out how to access these key/value pairs, i cant use explode() on & because that will give me

```
[0] => key1=value1
[1] => key2=value2
[2] => key3=value3
```

and i cant use $_POST['key1'] or $_GET['key1'] in php to access these values. What should i do!!! Thanks

And as a side question i notice .serilize() replaces line breaks with %0A and white spaces with +, how do i decode these values with php? Thanks again!

Edit:

Hey well the jquery code is fairly basic its :

```
var formSubmit = $(this).serialize();
$.post('ajax.php',{"formSubmit": "true", "formInfo": formSubmit}
```

Comment: How are you sending the variables to PHP? Post that code (your AJAX code).

Comment: Can you show the javascript statement sending the request?

Comment: For instance, I created this for another page. See the loaded content: http://jfcoder.com/test/serialize.php

Comment: @Ben - Add that code to your question.

Comment: You dont need to decode anything in php, simply provide your javascript code, i am sure u have some problems in it

Comment: @Ben - Where is the rest of the `$.post()` code?

Comment: See my answer, i hope solve you problem `print_r( $_POST['formInfo'] );
`

Comment: @Jared Whoops forgot the ) at the ends, thats it. I didnt need a callback function, i just want to pass the form data for php to process it

Comment: Why are you serializing your form, then including it in another object with a separate formSubmit? Couldn't you just add a (hidden) input with name formSubmit and value true? Or add the formSubmit value to the end of the formSubmit variable?

Comment: Probably should have named it something else besides "formSubmit", but i just wanted a quick what if php to process the code with if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']){ // then process form}, but probably the naming adds to the confusion of it

Comment: @Ben - You're sending a textural url-encoded string to the server as a variable, instead of as a series of variables to be url-decoded. There is no reason to do this - send it all as serialized, or JSON, or whatnot, but you're inadvertently making it hard on yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're submitting the form data with jQuery's Ajax functionality, there should not be a problem with using `.serialize()`. The server should see and urldecode automatically the POST content.

As a demonstration, see this code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="category-dynamic" class="dynamic">
   <fieldset id="inner-fieldset">
      <legend id="new-category">
        <label for="category-name">Category Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="category-name" value="" />
      </legend>
      <ul id="category-fields">
         <li>
           <label>Field #1:</label><br />
           <input type="text" name="fields[]" value="" />
         </li>
         <li>
           <label>Field #2:</label><br />
           <input type="text" name="fields[]" value="" />
         </li>
      </ul>
   </fieldset>
</form>
<h3>POST Result</h3>
<pre></pre>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('pre').html($('#category-dynamic').serialize());

    $.post("http://jfcoder.com/test/processor.php", $('#category-dynamic').serialize(), function(data){
         $('pre').html($('pre').html()+"\n\n"+data);
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

And the processor.php file contents:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

**EDIT 2**

I think your error is that you're sending the content in such a way as to make the form data be a text string instead of url-encoded content.

For instance, you could do this:

```
var formSubmit = $(this).serialize() + "&formSubmit=true";
$.post('ajax.php', formSubmit);
```

And you'd have the same effect, and the server would be able to expand your POST variables without incident.

**EDIT 3**

See this example:

Where the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var serial = $('#category-dynamic').serialize() + "&formSubmit=true";
    $('pre').html(serial);
    $.post("http://jfcoder.com/test/processor.php", serial, function(data){
         $('pre').html($('pre').html()+"\n\n"+data);
    });
});
```

Note the addition of the `"&formSubmit=true"` to the serial data. This outputs from the PHP page:

```
POST Result

category-name=&fields%5B%5D=&fields%5B%5D=&formSubmit=true

Array
(
    [category-name] => 
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [formSubmit] => true
)
```

**EDIT 4**

This uses the method you describe. See the difference?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var serial = $('#category-dynamic').serialize();
    $('pre').html(serial);
    $.post("http://jfcoder.com/test/processor.php", {"formSubmit":"true","serial":serial}, function(data){
         $('pre').html($('pre').html()+"\n\n"+data);
    });
});
```

OUTPUT

```
POST Result

category-name=&fields%5B%5D=&fields%5B%5D=

Array
(
    [formSubmit] => true
    [serial] => category-name=&fields%5B%5D=&fields%5B%5D=
)
```

Comment: @Ben - See Edit 4 for how your use differs in outcome from mine.

Comment: i think your right , the way i sent the post variables was pretty confusing and sending it all as one variable made it a lot smoother. It worked!!! THANK YOU!! I just found out about that too. Wow you definitely helped me out so much! Thanks again man.

Comment: @Ben - No problem. You might read up on jQuery's [merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) and [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), since you might need them one day.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json in jQuery and json_decode in php then.

- http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/
- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
- http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Serialize should work fine. JSON is just another way to submit data to the server, it shouldn't "fix" this problem.

Comment: It'll fix, as in the result we will have single object in JS and in PHP in result.

Comment: It's just another way of sending data.

Answer (score 0):

You values exists in `formInfo` index of $_POST array,

```
print_r( $_POST['formInfo'] );

echo $_POST['formInfo']['key1'];
```