# PHP unserialize error when deserializing jQuery serialized form

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with php after jquery .serialize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164691/what-to-do-with-php-after-jquery-serialize)

I am serializing the following form using jQuery, sending it to the server using ajax and deserializing using PHP.

When I deserializing I get the error:

`Error at offset 0 of 39 bytes`

```
<form  id="Marriage" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="city" class="txtt" value="city"/>
  <input type='button' value='Apply' id="msendsend" class="sendaf" name="jobforming"/>
</form>
```

Here is the jquery function to send this form

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#msendsend').click(function () {
        var id=getParam('ID');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"send.php",

            data:{option:'apply',  sr:$("form").serialize()},
            success:function (jd) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the server code:

```
 if($_REQUEST['option']=='catapply') {
    $sc=$_POST['sr'];
    mysql_query("insert into user_data(uid,data) values('$session->userid','$sc')");
  }
```

And here I am unserializing .

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from user_data");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $un = unserialize($row['data']);

            $city=$un['city'];
            echo $city;
        }
```

The data in the database is shown as

```
to=&select_category=25&msg=&city=laho
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, when you serialize a form and there is one input hidden it will skip it...you have the whole form hidden...

Comment: Lession to learn: Only two things have a similar name, it must not mean that they belong to each other. Here: PHP is not jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's serialize function is way different from PHP's. It creates a query string, as you can see in your database.
This format may be decoded in PHP with the [parse_str function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Use it instead of unserialize.

Instead of parsing it manually, though, you may be better off posting your form data as the query string:

```
data: $("form").serialize(),
```

You can add a hidden field to convey the option=apply value.

That way, you don't have to decode anything (it'll already be in $_POST) and you may insert every value in a separate row. It'll save you a lot of trouble in the future, e.g. when there's more data and you need to search through it.