# AJAX form submission in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have a problem when I try to send some data with `$.post(jquery ajax function)` - it's not working. My code is here:

```
$.post(
    $(this).attr("action"),
    {     
        task: "add",
        $(this).serialize()
    },
    function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0 ) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    }
);
```

I am guessing the problem is with the data being sent, actually I have one complete AJAX page with lots of switch case statements to perform so for that I need to specify the `task` variable every time I send and AJAX request.

If there are better solutions on how to solve this issue feel free to share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: $(this) referring to the form??

Comment: yes it refers to the form that i m submitting

Comment: can you brief your code more....!!

Comment: Actually this is the first time i am using that function $(this).serialize() function when sending the form, but the problem is the action for for this ajax request has lots of switch cases, so usually i used to use variable called "task" and specify the the operation, but now when i used the serialize() i dont know how to give, which operation to be performed in the switch statement.Hope your got what i was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

It should have been like below I think.

```
$.post(
    $(this).attr("action"),
    {task:"add",'data': $(this).serialize()},
    function(data){
        if(data.length > 0 ){
            alert("Success");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: it works but how would i receive that values from variable "data" in php action page. If u could share some idea on that Ankit.

Comment: how do you receive task in php? data will also be received same. Just replace 'task' to 'data' in your statement. i.e $_REQUEST['data']

Comment: This is probably not what you are looking for. Even if it would work, the server would only receive two post parameters, "task" and "data", the latter just being a long string of combined form field-value pairs.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg is right. Look here for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164691/what-to-do-with-php-after-jquery-serialize

Comment: yes Mr.Peter you are right, if u send it in variable data then all the values will get trued into very long string. Is there anything more effective to that.

Comment: @Chakra, please see Anthony's and my own answers (which are basically the same, but he was faster). I think they will both result in what you want, which is the form data received as individual parameters, in addition to the "task" parameter which will be received in exactly the same way.

Comment: Oh yes Mr.Peter the "task" will also be received in the same way. It was quite simple but i was banging my head for a long time. hahaha any ways thank for the great help :D. and I m sorry i cannot vote for ur answers because VOTE UP REQUIRES 15 REPUTATION which i dont seem to have at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this part:

```
{     
    task: "add",
    $(this).serialize()
}
```

That's going to throw a syntax error because it's not a valid object literal. Calling `$(this).serialize()` returns a string, which is the query string for the request. What you could do is this instead:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize() + '&task=add', function(data) {...});
```

Comment: Oh thank you Mr. Anthony . it worked so here we are actually trying to concatenate another string and then send it. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the part

```
{task:"add",$(this).serialize()}
```

is invalid as a label is required after the comma.

```
{task: "add", data: $(this).serialize()}
```

would at least result in a valid object, but not one that makes sense to post to the server.

I think the easiest solution would be something like

```
$.post($(this).attr("action"),
$(this).serialize() + '&task=add',
function(data){
 if(data.length > 0 ){
   alert("Success");
}
});
```